# MemCache object is not being instantiated inside a php file

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I'm trying to make this [example on php, mysql, and memcache](http://www.kutukupret.com/2011/05/04/memcached-and-php-caching-mysql-query-result/) works. I put the file in the `var/www/html` folder. This is the top of the content of the mc.php file.

```
<?php
  echo "test 1";
  $memcache = new Memcache;
  echo "test 2";
  ...
?>
```

When I run this `http://localhost/mc.php` in the browser, I get the following text: `test 1`.

Clearly, the memcache object is not being instantated. Yet, I've memcached installed. When I run this command in command line, I get this result

```
user1: ~$ ps ax | grep memcached
1037 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
2801 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto memcached
```

Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Turn on `display_errors` + set `error_reporting` to show you errors

Comment: Yes I'll turn it on. I didn't know that it was off by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the memcached the problem is that you haven't installed the Memcache php extension. I don't know which system you use. But in Debian and other Linux systems you can install that extension over the package manager.

```
apt-get install php5-memcache
```

After that reload the webserver or php process and you have the Memcache extension loaded. To check if the extension is loaded make a `phpinfo()` there you can search for **memcache** and you see if the module in available.

This is why you get only the first echo. PHP can't find the Memcache class / extension.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem thats a common problem.